# why does it say 0 commands synced when loading a cog

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to add cogs to my very long python discord bot, but when i added the cog it says 0 commands synced and i cant do the slash command in my server.
i am trying to implement a command that has basically everything i need as a test and i load the command. it recognises and loads the cog but it doesnt seem the load the command, im assuming the problem is in the cog and not in main.py.

main.py

```
imports

activities = [
    discord.Game(name="help"),
    discord.Game(name="me")
]

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

rcolor = [
    discord.Colour.blurple()
]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
    print("NOAAHBOT is ready, you can now leave the tab")
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blurple())
    channel = client.get_channel(channelidhere)
    embed.add_field(name=f'back online',
                    value='noaahbot has been updated.',
                    inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    try:
        synced = await client.tree.sync()
        print(f"synced {len(synced)} commands")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    while True:
        for activity in activities:
            await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

client.run("Token")
```

cog

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class SayCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.command(name="say", description="What should the bot say")
    @app_commands.describe(thing_to_say = "text")
    async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str | None):
        if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
            return await interaction.response.send_message("You require administator permisions to use this command")
        if thing_to_say is None:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'nothing to be said')
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'{thing_to_say}')


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(SayCog(client))`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading a normal command, not a slash command. To load a slash command inside a cog you have to do:

@app_commands.command() instead of @commands.command

Comment: that seemed to have worked. but now im having another problem if you can please help me here. here is the error that im getting.
'cogs.say' raised an error: TypeError: unknown parameter given: thing_to_say

Comment: @CYKLER your function is inside of a class so it should take `self` as the first parameter....